# Yii2: Add 'user_id' when create a post

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app

I have a 'post' table with attribute 'user_id' in it to know who have posted that post. I run into a problem, when create a post, the 'user_id' didn't add into database, which can't be null, so I can't continue from there. So how can I add 'user_id' of the user that is currently logging in, automatically.

I'm using Yii2 basic template.

Thanks

Comment: You need to post some codes to increase your chances of getting an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Or you could have a look at [Blameable Behavior](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-behaviors-blameablebehavior.html)

> BlameableBehavior automatically fills the specified attributes with the current user ID.

I use this in alot of my projects (often combined with `sluggable` and `timeable`) and its easy to use, just put the following in your Post model:

```
use yii\behaviors\BlameableBehavior;

public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        [
            'class' => BlameableBehavior::className(),
            'createdByAttribute' => 'user_id',
            'updatedByAttribute' => false,
            'attributes' => [
                ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_VALIDATE => ['user_id'] // If usr_id is required
            ]
        ],
    ];
}
```

*Referencing [Behavior validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29282401/validation-rules-on-behavior-created-attributes) on validation behaviors.*

If you want to do it manually like the other answers suggest, you need to change

```
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    }
```

to

```
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {
        $model->user_id = \Yii::$app->user->identity->id
        $model->save()
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    }
```

**Remember:** when you validate before inputting the user id, the user_id can't be required in your model rules!

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code

//To get whole logged user data

```
$user = \Yii::$app->user->identity;
```

//To get id of the logged user

```
$userId = \Yii::$app->user->identity->id
```

Look at the documentation for more details: [doc](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-user.html) .

Comment: Thank you, I can get the ID now, but how can I add it to post database, I'm sorry but I'm new.

Comment: what do u mean by post database? @Starite

Comment: @Bloodhound Sorry, my English is pretty bad, but I found a solution using beforeSave(), thank you :)

Comment: Sorry I forgot :) I kinda want to have a hidden input as current user ID, so when I click Create, It will be add to database without have to type the ID in the form. Can you help me more with it? @Bloodhound

Comment: for that you need  if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())&& $model->validate() ){$model->user_id =\Yii::$app->user->identity->id;$model->save();}

Comment: I've got it, Thank you :)

Comment: like to know why my answer was not accepted @Starite

Comment: @Bloodhound I'm sorry but your both method work and I'm using both in mine. But I can't accept both of you, Jorgen has more details in his answer so I accept him for other to see. If you really want it then I'll accept your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Apart from what Bloodhound suggest, you can also use the following code to get the currently logged in user ID:

```
$loggedInUserId = \Yii::$app->user->getId();
```